# Javascript ES6 Promise Function Options

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have an async function which can call one of multiple other async functions; I can split this up into multiple `.then.catch` chains, but I'm wondering if I can merge them together somehow.
What I have is:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (payload.method === 'a')
        doFunctionA(arg)
        .then((x) => resolve())
        .catch((error) => reject())
    else if (payload.method === 'b')
        doFunctionB()
        .then((x) => resolve())
        .catch((error) => reject())
});
```

That's simplified, but is there another way to write this so that the then and catch is only written once? Like:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var f = (payload.method === 'a' ? doFunctionA(arg) : doFunctionB());
    f()
    .then((x) => resolve())
    .catch((error) => reject())
});
```

Comment: If doFunctionA/B return promises there is not need to wrap them in a new Promise, just return their result

Comment: Just change f().then to f.then() and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `doFunctionA` and `doFunctionB` already return `Promises`, you don't have to wrap them in another `Promise`:

```
(payload.method === 'a' ? doFunctionA : doFunctionB)(arg)
  .then((x) => resolve())
  .catch((error) => reject())
```

Comment: Great. I knew it was something like that.
Is there anyway to do this in-line, or is it always declare the function and then use?

Comment: @theservant I've updated my answer if you don't want to use another function

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are very close to the right way, except you are calling `f` twice. Try something like :

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    (payload.method === 'a' ? doFunctionA : doFunctionB)(arg)
        .then((x) => resolve())
        .catch((error) => reject())
    ;
});
```

Still better is to return the function as suggested by @Patrick

```
return (payload.method === 'a' ? doFunctionA : doFunctionB)(arg);
```